# How to get user's Timezone in Django 1.3 Http Request

Tags: python, django, timezone, httprequest, django-1.3

I have read that there is a lot of timezone support available in *Django 1.4*, but how does one obtain user's timezone in ***Django 1.3***?

Once I have the timezone i.e. something like *'Europe\London'* or *'GMT+4:00'*, it is easy to use a *middleware* to set it into the `request.META` dict so that it is available with every request...

Answer (score 0):

The user's timezone isn't normally available to the server. If you look at your own web browser's request headers in something like http://www.myhttp.info/ you'll see there's nothing in there that gives a clue to your timezone.

However, if you can run some Javascript on the client side, you can use the `Date` class constructor and `Date.UTC` to examine the difference between local time and UTC on the client. That difference is the current time offset, which is the best you can reliably do.

Comment: Are you really sure? then, how does Django 1.4 support it? you can do something like `tz = request.session.get('django_timezone'); if tz: timezone.activate(tz)` in a middleware in Django 1.4 and you get user's timezone everywhere when available, check out this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: It doesn't go that far. At <https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone> it says that Django can't automatically determine the user's timezone, but it provides tools to help you get that information from the user.